# PNG Logo from Illustrator in Da Vinci aliasing issue

Tags: davinci-resolve

I need to put a logo watermark on a video but the aliasing is terrible. I already tried all the settings (premultiplied etc) in clip attributes. I also tried moving the vector over to Photoshop and exporting a .tiff file instead but the issue is still present. The aliasing is present both on the watermark as well as on the zoom animation (zooming from original size to smaller). How can I fix this? I really don't want to use After Effects for something this simple.

Thank you in advance!